# a variable doesn't save a return value from function

Tags: c

I am studying C in college, I'm working on a code that if the GPA of a student is less than 2 >> it adds 0.2 to it

the problem that in debugging ..the value of X = 0 , not equal to f (the return of the function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct user {
    int userID;
    char Firstname[25];
    float gpa;
};

int GPAedit (float x) {
    float f;

    if (x < 2)
        f = x + 0.2;
    else f = x;
    return f;
}

int GPAedit(float);

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    float x;
    struct user S[i];

    for (i == 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("enter user %d ID", i);
        scanf("%d", &S[i].userID);
        printf("enter user %d  name\n", i);
        scanf("%s", S[i].Firstname);
        printf("enter user %d GPA\n", i);
        scanf("%f", &S[i].gpa);

        x = GPAedit(S[i].gpa);

        S[i].gpa = x;

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {   
        printf("user %d ID\n", S[i].userID);
        printf("%s\n", S[i].Firstname);
        printf("%.4f\n", S[i].gpa);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Another issue: in your for loop, `i == 0` should be `i = 0`

Comment: Your code is pure C, remove the C++ tag

Comment: This is an unexpected twist on the `typedef` syntax!  I learned something today.

Comment: I'm still discovering the whole thing here ..be patient with me please :)

@chqrlie what's the typedef issue that you are talking about ?

Comment: I updated my answer.  My remark was not harsh: it is this first time I see a typedef with no name, you only get a warning for this, it is not an error but a very surprising use of `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GPAedit()` function is stripping off the precision part of your value by returning a `float` variable as `int`:

```
int GPAedit (float x )
{
    float f ;
    if ( x < 2)
        f = x+0.2 ;
    else f = x;
    return f;
}
```

It should return `float` like this:

```
float GPAedit (float x )
{
    float f ;
    if ( x < 2)
        f = x+0.2 ;
    else f = x;
    return f;
}
```

Also, you don't need to redefine it over your main function, since it's already defined up there, so remove this:

```
int GPAedit (float  );
```

from the line before `int main()`

Comment: You are absolutely Right ! ... Thanks a lot ,it works :)

Answer (score 3):

In the `main` function, you define `user` as

```
struct user S[i];
```

But `i` has the value `0` when this definition is executed.

Define the array with a size greater than 0.

`GPAedit` should be defined to return `float`.  Returning `int`, it truncates the value so instead of increasing by `0.2` points, it may actually reduce the low GPAs.

It would be more consistent to change the API this way:

```
void GPAedit(struct user *up) {
    if (up->gpa < 2)
        up->gpa += 0.2;
}
```

And call this function with the address of the structure:

```
GPAedit(&S[i]);
```

Also note that the `typedef` is useless in your definition of `struct user`.  `typedef` is used to create type aliases such as:

```
typedef struct user {
    int userID;
    char Firstname[25];
    float gpa;
} user;
```

You can then use `user` as a type instead of `struct user`.

Comment: I tried using a random number so i put "struct user S[10];" but still x doesn't change

Comment: wrong return type on `GPAedit()`, MehrdadMomeny was quicker to spot it!

Answer (score 1):

in `int GPAedit (float x)`, you return `int` so your float is truncated.

you probably ant to return `float`

Comment: MehrdadMomeny deserves the checkmark, he gave this answer first.

Comment: @chqrlie i checked his answer many times ,but it's removed... , didn't notice that it's only for 1 answer :D [STUPID] sorry :)..Thank you too